# Angular , when navigate to another page , slick of undefined error

Tags: angular, slick.js

I have 2 slick carousels  on main page `/home`

**slider.component.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('mainBannerModal') mainBannerModal: SlickCarouselComponent;
  @ViewChild('eventsModal') eventsModal: SlickCarouselComponent;

  next(modal) {
   if (modal) {
    modal.slickNext(); // when navigate to another page gives an error , even with condiition if modal
   }
  }

  startProgressbar() {
    this.resetProgressbar();
    this.percentTime = 0;
    this.tick = setInterval(this.interval.bind(this), 10);
  }

  interval() {
    this.percentTime += 1 / (this.time + 0.1);
    this.progressBarWidth = this.percentTime;
    if (this.percentTime >= 100) {
      this.next(this.mainBannerModal); // HERE I pass my exact slick modal and invoke function
      this.startProgressbar();
    }
  }

  resetProgressbar() {
    this.progressBarWidth = 0;
    clearTimeout(this.tick);
  }
```

**slider.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="mainSlider">
     <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #mainBannerModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
       ... carousel 1
    </ngx-slick-carousel>
</div>
<div *ngIf="eventsSlider">    
    <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #eventsModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
       ... carousel 2
    </ngx-slick-carousel>
</div>
```

When I navigate from `/home` page (where my slick carousels) to another page guess `/registration` , I have **infinitive** error logs

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slick' of undefined

Please help

**UPD 1**

FYI , I import slides on main page by this way

**main-page.component.html**

```
<section class="main">
  <app-slider mainSlider="true"></app-slider>
  <app-slider eventsSlider="true"></app-slider>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code snippets are missing some important parts, so can only guess...

1. You're calling `setInterval` but clearing it using `clearTimeout`.
   You should use `clearInterval` instead.

> `clearTimeout` is used with `setTimeout`.

2. The interval you're setting is probably left active, causing something to be called when your component has already been destroyed by the router.

Try implementing `OnDestroy` and call your reset method inside of `ngOnDestroy`:

```js
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
export class YourComponent implements OnDestroy
{
   ...

   private clearInterval(): void
   {
      if (this.tick)
      {
          clearInterval(this.tick);
          this.tick = null;
      }
   }

   ngOnDestroy()
   {
       this.clearInterval();
   }
}
```

When the user navigates to a new route, the router will destroy your component and call `ngOnDestroy` which will make sure the interval is cleaned.

Comment: Man , really thanks a lot XD . Indeed the problem was that I mistyped clearInterval with clearTimeout  and I have put clearTimeout onDestroy method, now it is working perfect . THanks :-)